# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible in keras

Tags: google-colaboratory, tf.keras, valueerror, precision-recall

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
```

This code works fine for metrics=['accuracy']), but it shows ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible for metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall makes sense only for binary classification. Your final layer has 5 nodes, which essentially means you have 5 classes. You should change recall to another metric. [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics) should help you choose an appropriate metric for your model. Categorical accuracy should be good enough to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I didn't get this clarification before. Truly helpful response.